# Icecast json-status.xls, not valid json answer with blank song title

Tags: javascript, php, json, xslt, icecast

When my track hasn't title in  tags, Icecast shows `-` instead of a blank
line, so, I get json like this (as example) and this json isn't valid because  `"title" : -` instead  `"title" : "-"` . I checked it here - http://jsonlint.com/ So, I cant't do `json_decode()`, function returns `null`

```
 {
     "icestats": {
         "admin": "admin@admin",
         "host": "host.com",
         "location": "Moscow",
         "server_id": "Icecast 2.4.2",
         "server_start": "Fri, 15 May 2015 16:25:24 +0300",
         "server_start_iso8601": "2015-05-15T16:25:24+0300",
         "source": [
             {
                 "audio_info": "channels=2;samplerate=44100;bitrate=192",
                 "channels": 2,
                 "genre": "various",
                 "listener_peak": 3,
                 "listeners": 0,
                 "listenurl": "http://mds.planeset.ru:8000/mds.mp3",
                 "samplerate": 44100,
                 "server_description": "Трансляции Модель Для Сборки
музыка",
                 "server_name": "Модель для сборки - музыка",
                 "server_type": "audio/mpeg",
                 "stream_start": "Fri, 15 May 2015 16:25:33 +0300",
                 "stream_start_iso8601": "2015-05-15T16:25:33+0300",
                 "title": -,
                 "dummy": null
             },
             {
                 "audio_info": "channels=2;samplerate=44100;bitrate=192",
                 "channels": 2,
                 "genre": "various",
                 "listener_peak": 10,
                 "listeners": 9,
                 "listenurl": "http://mds.planeset.ru:8000/mds_voice.mp3",
                 "samplerate": 44100,
                 "server_description": "Трансляции Модель Для Сборки -
голос",
                 "server_name": "Модель для сборки - голос",
                 "server_type": "audio/mpeg",
                 "stream_start": "Fri, 15 May 2015 16:25:33 +0300",
                 "stream_start_iso8601": "2015-05-15T16:25:33+0300",
                 "title": "Фред Саберхаген - Доброжил",
                 "dummy": null
             }
         ]
     }
}
```

This is example of json, as You can see in first case I have `title: -`  because of it I can not json_decode.

There is file xml2json.xslt from  Doeke Zanstra https://github.com/doekman/xml2json-xslt on server. This file, I guess, convert xml to json and maybe there is a way to add new rule to convert `-` to `null` in blank `title` line, but I don't know how I can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the XML to JSON template used by Icecast (xml2json.xslt). It is not converting a '-' to a string, maybe because it thinks it's a negative number although there is no digit. I'll try to look into it if I can figure out a bugfix. If someone else wants to have a jab at it and comes up with a good fix, I'd be grateful.

I'd like to note though that your assertion that your track doesn't have tags is wrong. Your source client software seems to set the *title* field of the stream to `-`. If it would set *title* to an empty string, then the conversion would actually return `null`. This is rooted in the fact that streaming MP3 is horribly broken due to how it was originally done by Shoutcast. There are no separate metadata fields for a track, there is just **one** field named *title* and a variety of conventions how it is used.

You can verify this yourself by setting it to an empty string. `http://mds.planeset.ru:8000/admin/metadata.xsl?song=&mount=%2Fmds.mp3&mode=updinfo&charset=UTF-8`

Thanks for the report, we can only fix bugs we know about. (Preferred place for bug reporting is http://trac.xiph.org )

Comment: I'd like to note though that your assertion that your track doesn't have tags is wrong. @TBR I understand this, but I have about thousand tracks, so I can't control tags of each :) Thank You for your answer.

Comment: Sure, just wanted to explain where the problematic string " - " comes from (your stream source). Obviously the mishanlding of "-" by the transform we use needs to be fixed.

Comment: I created a ticket on http://trac.xiph.org , source is MPD, I wrote it there.  Thank you again  :)

Comment: I've come up with a fix for the issue. Please try it out. https://trac.xiph.org/timeline?from=2015-05-16T17%3A50%3A33Z&precision=second

Answer (score 1):

If there is no way to get valid json, use:

```
$json = str_replace( '"title": -', '"title": null', $json );
```

to replace `"title": -` to `"title": null` before you use `json_decode()`.

Comment: I thought about this solution, but want to find  another way, get right json directly from server. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Of course, if possible, it will be better solution.